# String interpolation inside href in erb files doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I want to send a confirmation mail when the users sign up.

I am using devise and generated the devise view to modify them

```
File is /app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb

<% url = "#{ENV['ROOT_APP_URL']}/#/confirm/#{@token}" %>
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>
<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>
<%= url  %>
<a href="<%= url %>">Confirm My Account </a>
```

The issue is the output for the last line is

```
<a>Confirm My Account</a>
```

In the same time the line before it `<%= url %>` outputs `localhost:9001/#/confirm/XxyJGz`.
I tried using `raw` helper but same result

## Edit

Snippet from what I write and the output

**ERB**

```
<% url = "#{ENV['ROOT_APP_URL']}/#/confirm/#{@token}" %>
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>
<%= url  %>
<a href="<%=  url %>">Confirm My Account</a>

<% foo = "localhost:9001/#/confirm/XxyJGz" %> followed by <a href="<%= foo %>">Foo</a>
```

**Html**

```
<p>Welcome user@email.com</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

localhost:9001/#/confirm/NLirkXqjNq5dfwDti8Lc
<a target="_blank" class="">Confirm My Account</a>

followed by <a target="_blank">Foo</a>
```

Comment: The space after `Account` is missing, too. Is this your actual code and output?

Comment: That's odd. If the string interpretation wasn't working, I'd expect to see something like `<a href=>Confirm My Account</a>`. Not sure why it would make the ` href=` disappear. What happens if you try, `<% foo = "localhost:9001/#/confirm/XxyJGz" %>` followed by `<a href="<%= foo %>">Foo</a>`, same issue? And as @Stefan indicated, is this really representative of what you tried?

Comment: @lurker I updated the question with example

Comment: @NadeemKhedr you're editing the HTML output, aren't you? (the exclamation mark after the user's email is missing)

Comment: only the email part, because it was my real mail, the rest is copy paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an absoulte url, should have a protocol. so your `url` variable should start with `"http://"` or `"https://"`

Second thing is, you can use the normal link_to helpers.
You have to specify the `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` in your environments files (so you can point to localhost:9001 in your development environment and your production url in production).

this can be done with:

```
config/environments/development.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:9001' }
```

and your

```
config/environments/production.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'your-domain.com' }
```

Then in your views you should be able to use

```
<%= link_to confirmation_instructions_url(token: @token) %>
```

or whatever your url_helper is called.
Note that the url helper call must end in `_url` and not in `_path`, because